# Django admin: don't send all options for a field?

Tags: django, django-admin

One of my Django admin "edit object" pages started loading very slowly because of a ForeignKey on another object there that has a lot of instances. Is there a way I could tell Django to render the field, but not send any options, because I'm going to pull them via AJAX based on a choice in another SelectBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the other answers worked for me, so I read Django's internals and tried on my own:

```
class EmptySelectWidget(Select):
    """
    A class that behaves like Select from django.forms.widgets, but doesn't
    display any options other than the empty and selected ones. The remaining
    ones can be pulled via AJAX in order to perform chaining and save
    bandwidth and time on page generation.

    To use it, specify the widget as described here in "Overriding the
    default fields":

    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/

    This class is related to the following StackOverflow problem:

    > One of my Django admin "edit object" pages started loading very slowly
    > because of a ForeignKey on another object there that has a lot of
    > instances. Is there a way I could tell Django to render the field, but
    > not send any options, because I'm going to pull them via AJAX based on
    > a choice in another SelectBox?

    Source: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37327422/1091116
    """
    def render_options(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # copy the choices so that we don't risk affecting validation by
        # references (I hadn't checked if this works without this trick)
        choices_copy = self.choices
        self.choices = [('', '---------'), ]
        ret = super(EmptySelectWidget, self).render_options(*args, **kwargs)
        self.choices = choices_copy
        return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the queryset of that ModelChoiceField to empty in your ModelForm.

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fields['MY_MODEL_CHOIE_FIELD'].queryset = RelatedModel.objects.empty()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [...]
```

Comment: you meant objects.none(), right? This one didn't work - selecting anything other than the empty option gives "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `raw_id_fields`
By default, Django’s admin uses a select-box interface () for fields that are ForeignKey. Sometimes you don’t want to incur the overhead of having to select all the related instances to display in the drop-down.

`raw_id_fields` is a list of fields you would like to change into an Input widget for either a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField

Or you need to create a custom admin form

```
MY_CHOICES = (
        ('', '---------'),
)
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [...]
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyAdminForm
```

Comment: I already have a custom admin form, it's just that I'd like this widget not to have all <option> values.

Comment: Did you tried a ModelChoiceField with limited choices

Comment: I just tried your solution as in the example code and it has the same problem Muhammad Tahir's one has. I cannot actually select anything outside of the option list.